# [Here Maps][Here API] Waypoints Sequence: Daily limit for Add-On plans

Tags: routes, here-api

I am using the Waypoints Sequence API to get the optimal route sequence for my routes. I know that it has a limit for 10 requests per day in Freemium account, but when I accessed this link (https://developer.here.com/plan-features) and I found the description above:

> For Freemium and **Add-on** plans the following limits apply:
>
> - Custom Locations: you may upload a maximum of 3 layers with a maximum
>   of 100 polygons or polylines.
> - Waypoints Sequence: up to 10 requests per day.
> - Advanced Data Sets: up to 100 requests per hour and 1000 per day.

I found some threads explaining this limitation is just for Freemium accounts, but in Documentation the Add-On plan is included.

I've tested to run more than 10 times using my Add-On ApiKey and all works fine. I am just worried about this description including the Add-On plan in this limitation. Can someone help me?

#EDIT: I've tested here (doing more requests than 10) and the limit also happens to AddOn account. My test-team was tested this feature in the past year and this limit was not happening. Was this rule changed after March, 2020?